# Differences between hexaaqua cobalt (III) complex and hexammine cobalt (III) complex in aqueous solution

Tags: coordination-compounds

Why is $\ce{[Co(H2O)6]^3+}$ a strong oxidizing agent and $\ce{[Co(NH3)6]^3+}$ stable in Aqueous solution?

I think this has got to do with Pairing Energy and Ligand strengths of $\ce{H_2O}$ and $\ce{NH_3}$ but I haven't been able to get a definite answer so far, neither by my friends nor by google.